# Using tkinter for making gui in python

Tags: python, database, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a gui for a basic dbms project and while tkinter seems pretty easy for the most part i am unable to get how to use Entry to actually take the input and store it to use later (like an if condition or something) eg:

```
root = Tk()
label = Label(root,text="Testing")
label.grid(row=0)
entry = Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
```

Now what i want  to do is use the value/word i just wrote in the entry field to say just print it out on for example the console.

I thought we could just write

```
print(entry)
```

but that justs prints some random decimal on the console, ideally id like to store the value in some variable (if its not possible to use just "entry") so i can also use it in if conditions etc

I am using python 3

Comment: Have you read through the documentation on the Entry widget? The methods for retrieving the data are documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean you want to show some data in entry?

you may just do it like this:

```
v = StringVar()
e = Entry(master, textvariable=v)
e.pack()

v.set("a default value")
s = e.get()
```

you can just set the value of "v", for example the Entry show " a default value" string. And you can get the value use "get" method.

Comment: i am trying to combine it by using it such that i press a button and it prints the so i added s=v.get()
button=Button(text="enter",command=print(s))
button.grid(row=1) but that did not print anything

Comment: button=Button(text="enter",command=print_fun), and in print_fun you call print s

Comment: @hankyman i know its trivail but i dont get how to do that, the function cannot have any arguments cause command= thing does not take function name with the brackets, as in i cant do print_fun(s): print(s) button=Button(text="enter",command=print_fun) so how would i write it ?

Comment: func = (lambda x = s : print(x))  button=Button(text="enter",command=func)                                                    you just pass the argument to the func

Answer (score 1):

you have to retrieve the value:

```
s=entry.get()
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

By printing `entry` you are printing not what is in the entry, but the actual entry itself. You need to use `entry.get()` to grab the contents of the entry.

```
print(entry.get())
```